# Button under listview not working on click (getting a "Program has stopped" message)

Tags: listview

I have a fragment with one ListView (miLista) and a fixed button below it.
I want to be able to select one item from the ListView and then when clicking on the button (button2) show in another Activity more info about the item. 
My issue is that with the code shown below I manage to change the colour when clicking on an item from the list (miLista) but when I click on the button (button2) the application stops showing the messasge "Program has stopped".

```
     //Create an ArrayAdapter
     ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resumenLibro);

    //Select my ListView (milista)
    ListView miLista = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.milista);


    miLista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);

        }
    });

    //Button definition
    Button button2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Editorial);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                                   public void onClick(View view) {
                                       Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), EditorialActivity.class);
                                       i.putExtra("Editorial", (Editorial) libros[0].getEditorial());
                                       getActivity().startActivity(i);
                                   }
                                   });
```

Comment: Please add log for better understanding.

Comment: The application is showing a Listview with books names. There is a fixed button below the list. If you select one book and later click on the button I want to show more info about the book.

Comment: When I click on the book it is selected and changes colour but when I click on the button the application stops showing the message "Program has stopped".

Comment: I got your problem, But I want crash log from logcate to identify problem in program.

The most probable case is                                        i.putExtra("Editorial", (Editorial) libros[0].getEditorial());
this line.
But I want crash report to make sure.

Comment: the logs are quite big, I´m new, is there any way to upload files in "stackoverflow.com"?

Comment: Yes you can upload log same as you are adding code. 
or save log in text file upload it to some drive and share link.

Comment: 04-15 19:30:45.816: E/AndroidRuntime(14705): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 19:30:45.816: E/AndroidRuntime(14705): Process: andres.roberto.libreria, PID: 14705
04-15 19:30:45.816: E/AndroidRuntime(14705): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = andres.roberto.libreria.modelo.Editorial)
04-15 19:30:45.816: E/AndroidRuntime(14705):  at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1527)

Comment: You were right Keyur Thumar, the error was that I was using a non Serializable Object (Dirección) inside a Serializable Object (libros). I made Dirección a Serializable Object and the application is working. The error was in the line that you mentioned.